# Can I use rails_admin with mongoid 4.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, rails-admin

Can I use Mongoid and MongoDB with RailsAdmin? I can't seem to find any place that confirms that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/tree/master/lib/rails_admin/adapters/mongoid) is confirmation of your question. rails_admin is support mongoid.